# Reference one string from another string in custom xml file from resourse

Tags: android, xml, string

in resourse values I have one xml file, here i have facebook_app_id value:

```
 <string name="facebook_app_id">1769573166657682</string>
```

I need to reuse this values in another tag

```
<string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb1769573166657682</string>
```

Can I use value of facebook_app_id like this?

```
<string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb@string/facebook_app_id</string>
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use this way ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is concatenate a String and a String resource. I am afraid this is not possible in android through xml files.

What you can do is declare the two string and have a utility method that concatenate them.

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">1769573166657682</string>

<string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb$1s</string>
```

and then just use String.format to replace the first string parameter with the app id.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that is not possible in strings.xml.

What you can do is create the final string programmatically. Something like.

```
    String outStr = getString(R.string.fb) + 
  " " + getString(R.string.facebook_app_id);
```